# Identifying twitter handle in a plain text sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I need help identifying twitter handles (I think it's called a handle..) inside plain-text sentences and wrap a span tag around the handle.

So if I have a sentence constructed like this:

```
I can't wait to watch the 2012 London Olympic Games! @london2012
```

I need to find the handle and wrap a span tag around it:

```
I can't wait to watch the 2012 London Olympic Games! <span>@london2012</span>
```

Here is what I attempted with:

```
function findHandle(text) {
    var handle = text.substr(text.indexOf("@"), text.indexOf(" "));
    return text.replace(handle, "<span>" + handle + "</span>");
}
```

My code isn't working as planned. What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: What if there's no space after the handle?

Comment: That was one of the problems I ran into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your text-content is in a `div` element, the following seems to work (though not tested exhaustively):

```
$('div').html(
    function(i,html) {
        return html.replace(/@[\d\D]+\b/g, '<span>$&</span>');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GqUbT/).

The above seemed a [little fragile](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GqUbT/10/), so I've changed the regex selector to:

```
$('div').html(
    function(i,html) {
        return html.replace(/(@\w+)/g, '<span>$&</span>');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GqUbT/1/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions, at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: You're very welcome, and I'm glad to have helped! =) (Also, added a link to show *why* the first posted code 'seemed a little fragile.')